# Selecting Lead status qualified not converting lead

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

When a user selects 'Qualified', the Lead doesn't Convert and this is messing with our reports.

I would like to not allow users to select the Lead Status 'Qualified', and the only way for a Lead to have a 'Qualified' status is by clicking the standard out of the box Convert button.  Is this possible?

Lead status is Qualified but did not convert:

[image]

Current Picklist values:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This validation rule ought to do it:
`NOT(isconverted) && ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Qualified')`

Comment: \I'm asking if it's possible to not let users select 'Qualified'.  I only want the Lead status to be qualified once a Lead has been converted.

Comment: Ah, i get it.... I updated my answer